# Forma correcta en el uso de la clase Scanner

Tags: scanner

Me gustaría saber si esta forma sería correcta a la hora de estructurar un programa usando metodos y la clase Scanner.

Como podéis ver yo pido por teclado los datos una vez llamo a la función contratar pero no sé si estructuralmente sería correcto así o cualquier interacción a la hora de pedir datos debería hacerse desde el main y no desde un método. (He cortado parte del main y del metodo para que se vea más claro).

```js
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        int option = -1;

        while (option != 0) {
            System.out.println("0.- Salir \n 1.- Contratar");
            option = kb.nextInt();
            switch (option) {

                case 0: 
                    System.exit(0);

                    break;
                case 1: 

                    contratar();
                    break;

                default:
                    System.err.println("Elige una de las opciones disponibles.");

            }
        }

    }
    
    // Metodo en cuestión
    
    public void contratar() {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Dime el nombre del empleado: ");
        String nom = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Apellido: ");
        String ape = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Numero de cuenta bancaria: ");
        String ncuenta = teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Email: ");
        String email = teclado.nextLine();
        empleados.add(new Empleado(nom, ape, ncuenta, email));
        }
```

**Muchas gracias por la ayuda!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependiendo del objetivo de tu programa, se puede definir si la estructura que elegiste para desarrollarlo es correcta o no. Con el ejemplo que pusiste no impacta mucho que declares un scanner en un método o lo tengas en tu método `main()`. Porque también lo puedes pasar como parámetro desde tu clase main al método `contratar()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    int option = -1;

    while (option != 0) {
        System.out.println("0.- Salir \n 1.- Contratar");
        option = kb.nextInt();
        switch (option) {

            case 0: 
                System.exit(0);

                break;
            case 1: 

                contratar(kb);
                break;

            default:
                System.err.println("Elige una de las opciones disponibles.");

        }
    }

}

// Metodo en cuestión

public void contratar(Scanner teclado) {

    System.out.println("Dime el nombre del empleado: ");
    String nom = teclado.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Apellido: ");
    String ape = teclado.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Numero de cuenta bancaria: ");
    String ncuenta = teclado.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Email: ");
    String email = teclado.nextLine();
    empleados.add(new Empleado(nom, ape, ncuenta, email));
    }
```

Dicho sea de paso, si quieres mejorar el ingreso de información hacia tu programa recomendaría crear una UI para este formulario, ahi si puedes restringir muchas cosas, como por ejemplo: el formato del correo sea correcto, formato de la cuenta bancaria, nombre del empleado no tenga números ( a menos que existe un nombre con números bajo caso de uso), etc.

Comment: Aún no manejo muy bien las UI ya que llevo poco tiempo programando pero intentaré mejorar esa parte y crear una, Muchas gracias por la respuesta!

Answer (score 1):

en estos casos puedes hacer una variable global del tipo Scanner y lo usas en ambos metodos, asi no repites codigo

```java
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int option = -1;

        while (option != 0) {
            System.out.println("0.- Salir \n 1.- Contratar");
            option = kb.nextInt();
            switch (option) {

                case 0: 
                    System.exit(0);

                    break;
                case 1: 

                    contratar();
                    break;

                default:
                    System.err.println("Elige una de las opciones disponibles.");

            }
        }

    }

    // Metodo en cuestión

    public void contratar() {
        System.out.println("Dime el nombre del empleado: ");
        String nom = kb.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Apellido: ");
        String ape = kb.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Numero de cuenta bancaria: ");
        String ncuenta = kb.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Email: ");
        String email = kb.nextLine();
        empleados.add(new Empleado(nom, ape, ncuenta, email));
        }
```

Por lo demas lo tienes bien estructurado en metodos y los usas correctamente